# In MIPS TLBs, is it possible for two entries to be identical except for the ASID field?

Tags: linux, mips, paging, tlb, mips64

Is it possible to map two entries with the same virtual address and physical address except that the ASIDs are different?

Comment: Sure, why would it not be? Two processes could be using the same .so mapped to the same virtual address.

Comment: Thanks! From a software perspective it makes sense. I was not sure if TLB hardware is capable of generating an Index given the same VA.

Answer (score 0):

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-tlbs.pdf

> > A Real TLB Entry
> >
> > Finally, let’s briefly look at a real TLB. This example is from the MIPS
> >     R4000 [H93], a modern system that uses software-managed TLBs; a slightly
> >     simplified MIPS TLB entry can be seen in Figure 19.4.
> >
> > The MIPS R4000 supports a 32-bit address space with 4KB pages. Thus,
> >     we would expect a 20-bit VPN and 12-bit offset in our typical virtual address.
> >     However, as you can see in the TLB, there are only 19 bits for the
> >     VPN; as it turns out, user addresses will only come from half the address
> >     space (the rest reserved for the kernel) and hence only 19 bits of VPN
> >     are needed. The VPN translates to up to a 24-bit physical frame number
> >     (PFN), and hence can support systems with up to 64GB of (physical) main
> >     memory (2^24 4KB pages).
> >
> > There are a few other interesting bits in the MIPS TLB. We see a global
> >     bit (G), which is used for pages that are globally-shared among processes.
> >     Thus, if the global bit is set, the ASID is ignored. We also see the 8-bit
> >     ASID, which the OS can use to distinguish between address spaces (as
> >     described above). One question for you: what should the OS do if there
> >     are more than 256 (2^8) processes running at a time? Finally, we see 3
> >     Coherence (C) bits, which determine how a page is cached by the hardware
> >     (a bit beyond the scope of these notes); a dirty bit which is marked when
> >     the page has been written to (we’ll see the use of this later); a valid bit
> >     which tells the hardware if there is a valid translation present in the entry.
> >     There is also a page mask field (not shown), which supports multiple page
> >     sizes; we’ll see later why having larger pages might be useful. Finally,
> >     some of the 64 bits are unused (shaded gray in the diagram).

Yes, according to an operating system textbook(Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces), for some MIPS systems (e.g.,e MIPS R4000), they do have this scheme. For example, the global pages from the OS shared between 2 processes meets your description.